# Ignoring midnight in date formats with CsvHelper.CsvWriter

Tags: csvhelper

By default, CsvHelper.CsvWriter seems to be outputting midnight in the date string for DateTime types. I've been trying to find a good way to deal with this globally so I don't have to do it on every field. Right now this is what I'm doing:

```
using System;
using CsvHelper;

namespace OsaDataManagement.Service.Extensions
{
    public static class CsvWriterExtensions
    {
        public static void SetDateFormat(this CsvWriter csv,
            string dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy")
        {
            csv.Configuration.TypeConverterOptionsCache
                .GetOptions<DateTime>().Formats = new[] { dateFormat };
            csv.Configuration.TypeConverterOptionsCache
                .GetOptions<DateTime?>().Formats = new[] { dateFormat };
        }
    }
}
```

However, what I'd like to do is be able to check the date to see if it has a time value. If not, I'll use just the date, otherwise I'll use the full date/time format. I don't see an easy way to do this though. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

CsvHelper outputs `DateTime` with the standard `ToString()` method unless you specify the formatting, such as in your example extension method. Another way to specify the formatting would be through a custom converter class where you could check for midnight and conditionally apply the formatting.

```cs
public class MidnightDateTimeConverter : DateTimeConverter
{
    public override string ConvertToString(object value, IWriterRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return base.ConvertToString(value, row, memberMapData);
        }

        var date = (DateTime)value;

        if (date.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds == 0)
        {
            return date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        }

        return base.ConvertToString(value, row, memberMapData);
    }
}
```

You could then use it as follows. It worked for both `DateTime` and `DateTime?` in my tests.

```cs
csv.Configuration.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<DateTime>(new MidnightDateTimeConverter());
```